# How to Install Kiali Dashboard with prometheus in place in GKE with default istio beta feature?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, prometheus, istio, kiali, istio-kiali

I have been trying to install Kiali on an **Istio (beta) enabled GKE cluster**, I am following the official documentation to install Kiali using [this link](https://kiali.io/documentation/v1.21/quick-start/) but Prometheus is somehow damaged since GCP has changed the name of Prometheus from **"Prometheus" to "promsd"** and Kiali dashboard keeps on pointing to `http://prometheus.istio-system.com:9090` instead of `http://promsd.istio-system.com:9090`. How should I fix this issue in a **default** **ISTIO ENABLED GKE Cluster**?

Comment: Just an idea from me, I would recommend to use istio on-prem instead of the addon, addon is old compare to on-prem version, and you can [install](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/getting-started/#download) the on-prem version with istioctl in 3minutes. Then install kiali and prometheus addons, as mentioned [here](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/observability/gateways/#configuring-remote-access). With istio 1.6+ you can use prometheus to scrape metrics like with prometheus helm, more informations [here](https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/integrations/prometheus/#option-2-metrics-merging).

Comment: Got it, thanks I'll take a look.

Answer (score 2):

To make it work I had to edit `ConfigMap` called **kiali** inside of `istio-system` namespace. I added this lines under the `external_services` section:

```
prometheus:
  url: http://my-prometheus-kube-prometh-prometheus.default.svc.cluster.local:9090/
```

[image]

Comment: I know - this is old post and by now you might find out a solution. but I think the prometheus is not install and that's why it's not there.  use kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/istio/istio/release-1.12/samples/addons/prometheus.yaml to install that and then restart istio-egresgateway and other pods

Comment: Newest version does not work. Kiali cannot find external prometheus in the same cluster even after providing the correct entry in the CM.

Answer (score 1):

You could check the kiali configmap in namespace istio-system (assuming you used the default namespace for istio installation).
There should be a prometheus tag below external services. Change it and restart the kiali pod.

**Update 20200821** : our config map (Istio (v1.5.6) installed via istioctl)

```
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: kiali
  namespace: istio-system
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/istio-system/configmaps/kiali
  uid: 660a2bfe-c71b-45ab-a438-ed61532dd8e3
  resourceVersion: '31024421'
  creationTimestamp: '2020-07-24T10:18:24Z'
  labels:
    app: kiali
    operator.istio.io/component: AddonComponents
    operator.istio.io/managed: Reconcile
    operator.istio.io/version: 1.5.6
    release: istio
  annotations:

data:
  config.yaml: |
    istio_component_namespaces:
      grafana: istio-system
      tracing: istio-system
      pilot: istio-system
      prometheus: istio-system
    istio_namespace: istio-system
    auth:
      strategy: login
    deployment:
      accessible_namespaces: ['**']
    login_token:
      signing_key: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    server:
      port: 20001
      web_root: /kiali
    external_services:
      istio:
        url_service_version: http://istio-pilot.istio-system:8080/version
      tracing:
        url: 
        in_cluster_url: http://tracing/jaeger
      grafana:
        url: 
        in_cluster_url: http://grafana:3000
      prometheus:
        url: http://prometheus.istio-system:9090
```

Comment: Peter, I tried this approach but it seems that the Prometheus URL is not set in Configmap of kiali. Please find the config map here--> https://notepad.pw/41oe8i2l.

Comment: How did you install istio ? and what version of istio did you install ?

Comment: Peter, I followed the following instructions- https://cloud.google.com/istio/docs/istio-on-gke/installing 

And since, I am using GKE 1.16, istio version is Istio 1.4.6- https://cloud.google.com/istio/docs/istio-on-gke/versions

Comment: perhaps you can just add the "external services" section ? (and restart kiali)

Comment: @Peter, Changing the entries in the CM has no affect.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error message (Not in GCP), and got resolved it by installing Prometheus:

```
$ kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/istio/istio/release-1.13/samples/addons/prometheus.yaml
```

> replace the `release-1.13` with your `istio` version

https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/integrations/prometheus/